# How can I group the data in 5 age brackets: “<20“, “20-39“, “40-59“, “60-79“, “>=80“ with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I group the data in 5 age
brackets: “<20“, “20-39“, “40-59“, “60-79“, “>=80“
with SQL

only made the first age but don't know how to continue

Comment: Look into `case expression`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go backwards in the logic.

```
CASE
WHEN AGE >= 80 THEN 'AGE IS GT 80'
WHEN AGE >= 60 THEN 'AGE IS BETWEEN 60-79'
WHEN AGE >= 40 THEN 'AGE IS BETWEEN 40-59'
WHEN AGE >= 20 THEN 'AGE IS BETWEEN 20-39'
ELSE 'AGE IS LT 20'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

No `CASE` needed:

```
SELECT g.AgeGroup, t.* 
FROM [your table] t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 AgeGroup
    FROM (VALUES
        (20), (40), (60), (80), (9999)
    ) v(AgeGroup)
    WHERE AgeGroup > t.Age
    ORDER BY AgeGroup
) g
```

The advantage here is it sets you up to be data driven. You can eventually convert this from a table-value constructor to a real table that can have things like a description, index, or other info stored for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Age < 20 THEN 'Bucket1'
     WHEN Age >= 20 and Age < 40 THEN 'Bucket2'
     WHEN Age >= 40 and Age < 60 THEN 'Bucket3'
     etc...
     ELSE 'No Bucket' END AS AgeBucket;
```